# Given `T` and `U` where `T extends U` how to return a `U`

Tags: java, generics, option-type

Given an API like:

```
class Bar { ... }
class Foo extends Bar { ... }
```

In Java's `Optional` type, we can say:

```
Optional<Foo> fooOption = ...
fooOption.orElse(aFoo) // returns something of type Foo
```

But, since `Foo` is a `Bar`, I would like to be able to say:

```
Optional<Foo> fooOption = ...
fooOption.orElse(aBar) // returns something of type Bar
```

As an exercise, I wanted to accomplish this with another type:

```
public abstract class Option<T> {
    // this doesn't compile
    public abstract <U super T> U orElse(U other);
}
```

How would I rewrite this to compile, but also support the ability to widen the type when desired at the same time?

Comment: `abstract class Option<T, U> { public abstract <T extends U> U orElse(U other);}` ? why would you name a method `orElse` - this might confuse people that expect `Optional.orElse`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But, since `Foo` is a `Bar`

But `Bar` is not a `Foo`. What I mean is that you can do this:

```
Optional<Bar> fooOpt = Optional.of(new Foo());
Bar bar = fooOpt.orElse(new Bar());
```

But you can't do the same thing with `Optional<Foo>` because it violates type constraints of [`Optional.orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) method.

In hypothetical implementation of `Option<T>` you should explicitly define `U` as a supertype of `T`

```
public class Option<U, T extends U> {
    T value;

    public U orElse(U other) {
        if (value != null) {
            return value;
        }
        return other;
    }
}
```

In that case you could wrote a code like this

```
Option<Foo, Bar> fooOpt = Option.of(new Foo());
Bar bar = fooOpt.orElse(new Bar());
```

Comment: I agree that `Bar` is not a `Foo`, but I should be able to provide a `Bar` value and get a `Bar` typed reference for either the `Foo` contained or the `Bar` I've provided.

Comment: I would like to specify the `U` type *implicitly* at the time I call the method.

Comment: Defining my `Optional<Foo>` as `Optional<Bar>` widens the type in all situations, where I only want to widen it in a specific situation.

Comment: Rather than `Foo` and `Bar`, consider some real classes ... you have an `Optional<Integer> oint` and you are trying to have `oint.orElse(...)` return a `Number`. That `Number` could be a `Long` or a `Double` or a `BigDecimal`! Or, worse yet, you could hav `oint.orElse(...)` return an `Object` in which case it could literally be *anything*... This doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: @Scooby unfortunately you can't do that because it breaks type bound declaration defined in [JLS§4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4). however you can define  `<U> U orElse(U other)` and do runtime type check with unchecked cast. I'll update my answer.

Comment: No need. I think given the situation I'd like to avoid that. I think your answer is the best we can do.

Answer (score 3):

Since `U` should be the super-type of `T`, you could do:

```
public abstract class Option<U, T extends U> {

    public abstract of(T value);

    public abstract U orElse(U other);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own method using `map` to expand the type:

```
public static <U, T extends U> U orElse(Optional<T> tOpt, U u) {
    return tOpt.<U>map(Function.identity()).orElse(u);
}
```

Comment: Obviously not. I just wanted to make it reusable.

Comment: This is not a bad solution, but I'd like it to be a object method, not a static.

Comment: @Scoobie that may simply not be possible.

Comment: @Scoobie The only way would be to write a wrapper class adding this functionality. It does not bring much though.

Answer (score 2):

There is a basic premise that is flawed in your question:

> In Java's Optional type, we can say:
>
> Optional fooOption = ...
> fooOption.orElse(aFoo) // returns something of type Foo
> But, since Foo is a Bar, I would like to be able to say:
>
> Optional fooOption = ...
> fooOption.orElse(aBar) // returns something of type Bar

A Foo is a Bar, but a Bar is not a Foo. If your Generic is defined as this:

```
Optional<Foo> fooOption = ...
```

Then you can return anything that is of type `Foo`. A `Bar` is **not** of type `Foo`.

If you had an additional object:

```
class FooBar extends Foo{}
```

Then you could cast it to a foo in your example:

> Optional fooOption = ...
>
> fooOption.orElse(aFooBar) // returns something of type Foo

Or, optionally, if you had defined your `Optional` as `Optional<Bar>` then you could use either `Foo` or `Bar` or `FooBar` objects, since they are all of or inherit from type `Bar`.

As to the second part of your question:

```
public abstract class Option<T> {
    // this doesn't compile
    public abstract <U super T> U orElse(U other);
}
```

Just by writing this with the common supertype:

```
public abstract class Option<T> {
    // this now compiles.
    public abstract T orElse(T other);
}
```

You're saying that anything that is **of** or **inherits from** type T is acceptable.

Comment: Your conclusion is right, but it provides the reverse functionality. I want to *widen* the type. Meaning, I want anything that is **of** or **can be inherited from to produce `T`**.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing. Anything that has a common superclass of T.